# python tkinter main window

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to open a code with pycharm and the following lines are the begining . but it doesn't open any window . what should I do ?

```
import tkinter
mainwindow=tkinter.Tk()
mainwindow.title("Calculator")
mainwindow.geometry('480x240')
buttonOne= tkinter.Button(mainwindow,text='1')
```

it runs and instantly closes without opening any window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make sure the window doesn't close you need the mainloop function.

```
import tkinter
mainwindow=tkinter.Tk()
mainwindow.title("Calculator")
mainwindow.geometry('480x240')
buttonOne= tkinter.Button(mainwindow,text='1')
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are missing pack, grid or place.  buttonOne= tkinter.Button(mainwindow,text='1').pack()

Comment: He asked how to make sure the window runs continously. But you are right I should have added those.